# Subscribe to RxJava Observable in the Background from Spring

Tags: java, spring, rx-java

I have an RxJava Observable that I'd like to process in the background in my web application.  This is so that the service can react to an event on a message queue.  Is there a Spring configuration that would allow me to subscribe to this Observable directly?

Something like the Spring TaskExector, that would allow for a background thread to handle the Observable events.  But something a little more sophisticated where I wouldn't have to hold the thread alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have done is have a Spring service that creates the Observable and subscribes to it in an `@PostConstruct` method, and unsubscribes in an `@PreDestroy`. This allows for stuff like counters and parallelism controls being exposed via JMX, and one can even stop/restart the observable via JMX or via service methods.

Comment: Nice.  Works perfect. Thank you.